# Android.how to calculate the wide of string?

Tags: android

MY code is

```
 Paint paint= new Paint();
 paint.setTextSize(size); 
 int iRet = 0; 
 if (str != null && str.length() > 0) {
     int len = str.length(); 
     float[] widths = new float[len]; 
     paint.getTextWidths(str, widths); 
     for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
     iRet += (int) Math.ceil(widths[j]); 
    } 
}
 return iRet;
```

I want to get the width of string ,but the return result has errors with TextView.

Don't know the right way.

thanks.

I show it in the virtual machine.

Comment: what you actually want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use canvas,Once a time I found the Textview can't show my text in right size ,so I use Canvas draw the text out ,the I get the width I want,that's maybe some wrong cause by dp,sp or px.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate text width you should use:

[`public float measureText (String text)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29)

method in class Paint, it will return measured width of text in paint.

Comment: I have try ,but the return result seems doesn't conclude the word space.what shown in textview is wider than what returned by measureText

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
int width = paint.measureText("this text");
```

measureText(String text) will return width of text.

Comment: I have try ,but the return result seems doesn't conclude the word space.what shown in textview is wider than what returned by measureText

Answer (score 0):

you can measure it by calling the measureText() of paint class here is the code for that-

```
Paint p=new paint();

int value = p.measureText("give input string to measure");
```